# WAV to MP3 - Java lib example

Tags: java, mp3, wav, javasound, lame

is there any example on how to use LameOnJ, Pure Java Mp3 Encoder etc. to encode WAV format to MP3 in java? Example code, tutorial anything would be great!

I'm fully confused in libraries right now; tried Tritonus lib but it gave me:

```
Error: Unsupported conversion: MPEG1L3 from PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Maybe thats because I use Mac OS - but I followed Linux instructions as there's no MAC instructions available?! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative, use [**JAVE** (**J** ava **A** udio **V** ideo **E** ncoder) library](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/):

> The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the
>   ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to
>   transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example
>   you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX
>   video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, **you can convert a
>   WAV audio file to a MP3** or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and
>   transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing
>   their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers
>   and operations are supported by JAVE.

Comment: @lbstr Sure, here it is: http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php?PHPSESSID=ogb4vps952ql5a8ambqf8topo0

Comment: I tried this one but I'm getting it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException which says that MultimediaInfo info is null... its in Encoder class. Any ideas?

Comment: I think its because of ffmpeg - I use Mac os and there's no file provided by Jave by default but there're instructions on how to get it worked..

Answer (score 2):

ON website of Jave for Java:

JAVE is not pure Java: it acts as a wrapper around an ffmpeg (http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/) executable. ffmpeg is an open source and free software project entirely written in C, so its executables cannot be easily ported from a machine to another. You need a pre-compiled version of ffmpeg in order to run JAVE on your target machine. The JAVE distribution includes two pre-compiled executables of ffmpeg: a Windows one and a Linux one, both compiled for i386/32 bit hardware achitectures. This should be enough in most cases. If it is not enough for your specific situation, you can still run JAVE, but you need to obtain a platform specific ffmpeg executable :)